# jQuery - add a show/hide button to each DIV dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn jQuery... everything is going slow & steady. Not complaining. However I like to challenge myself to do something different whenever that tutorial I'm doing is showing me something.

So this is what I have:

- A HTML page with some DIVs.
- I want to dynamically add a SHOW/HIDE button at the end of each DIV.
- If I click that button that DIV above that show/hide button should disappear.
- The HIDE button should become SHOW. If I click it again it should show the DIV again.

---

I know how to add a show/hide button at the end of each div.
I don't know how to tell each button that the DIV above him should be hidden.

The divs do not have an unique ID so I'm thinking that I should also add an unique ID to each DIV. I want to do this with jQuery.

So I'm thinking that I should do some kind of foreach loop. I should go trough each DIV, add an unique ID, add the unique show/hide button that would tell the exact DIV number to hide/show.

Did I got the logic right? Can anyone show me the exact syntax? I'm not only looking for the right code but also see if I have the right logic.

Thank You

Comment: add a click event to your button and ... $(this).parent().hide() shall do the trick. No need for unique id. using the DOM for that shall be enough

Comment: could you make a fiddle of just the html at least, so I can see what you mean? Then I can give tips for the JS. Help me help you.

Comment: $(this).sibling().toggle could work too. it depends on how your divs are set. Look selectors. http://overapi.com/jquery/

Comment: "*I know how to add a show/hide button at the end of each div.*" – well, show us how you do that, and the HTML with which you're working, and we'll show how to go further and add the functionality,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
  if ($(this).text() == 'Show') {
    $(this).text('Hide');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Show');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>a
  <button>Hide</button>
</div>
<div>b
  <button>Hide</button>
</div>
<div>c
  <button>Hide</button>
</div>
<div>d
  <button>Hide</button>
</div>
```

Or did you mean like this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).prev().toggle();
  if ($(this).text() == 'Show') {
    $(this).text('Hide');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Show');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>a</span>
  <button>Hide</button>
</div>
<div><span>b</span>
  <button>Hide</button>
</div>
<div><span>c</span>
  <button>Hide</button>
</div>
<div><span>d</span>
  <button>Hide</button>
</div>
```

or like this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).prev().toggle();
  if ($(this).text() == 'Show') {
    $(this).text('Hide');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Show');
  }
});
```

```css
div {display: inline}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>a</div>
  <button>Hide</button><br/>

<div>b</div>
  <button>Hide</button><br/>

<div>c</div>
  <button>Hide</button><br/>

<div>d</div>
  <button>Hide</button><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks! The second example is what I wanted. Everything looks so simple. I started to do a foreach and add a number to the ID so each ID would be unique. Then I was telling the button to look for the id, etc. It seems that I don't yet understand the prev(), toggle(). All I had to do was add your button code then dynamically add a button at the end of each of my DIVs.

Comment: Or perhaps you don't understand $(this) selects the element you clicked. prev then chooses the element that is the previous sibling, and .toggle changes between showing and hiding the element.

Comment: Nomally I wouldn't use `$(this).prev().toggle();`, I would use `$(this).closest('div').find('span').toggle()` instead.  Not quite as fast, but you can move the button around within the div and the code would still work.